# Calculation of an integral from BCS superconducting theory

Tags: integration

How do I calculate the following integral?
$$\int_0^{\infty} d z ~z^{1 / 2}\left[\frac{\tanh ((z-1) / 2 t)}{2(z-1)}-\frac{1}{2 z}\right]=\ln \left(\frac{8 C}{\pi e^2 t}\right),$$
where $C=e^\gamma$ and $\gamma$ is the Euler constant.

This is the integral in BCS superconducting theory to calculate the transition temperature in 3D space.
Here we may use the residue theorem but I don't know how to process it next.

Further, how do I calculate the 2D space scenario?
$$\int_0^{\infty} d z \left[\frac{\tanh ((z-1) / 2 t)}{2(z-1)}-\frac{1}{2 z + a}\right],$$
where $a>0$ is a constant.

Comment: Your "2D space scenario" appears to diverge at $z=0$

Comment: [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant) is usually denoted $\gamma\approx 0.577$. It may be confusing to denote $e^\gamma$ by "$\gamma$" and call it Euler's constant.

Answer (score 2):

**Remark:** Your stated equality is not true, as seen below.

[image: Equality Check]

With that out of the way, we can at least express your integral in a different form that may be of interest. It is unlikely to have a general closed-form expression.

---

Consider the general parametrised integral:

$$I(w):=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\left(\frac{\tanh\left(w\cdot\frac{x-1}{2t}\right)}{2(x-1)}-\frac{w}{2x+a}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$ Differentiating in $w$, we have $$I'(w)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{4t}\operatorname{sech}^2\left(w\cdot\frac{x-1}{2t}\right)-\frac{1}{2x+a}\right)\mathrm{d}x.$$

Now utilise the series representation $$\operatorname{sech}^2(z)=-4\sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^kke^{-2zk}\quad\text{with}\quad\Re(z)>0,$$ to arrive at \begin{align*}I'(w)&=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{2x+a}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^kk}{t}e^{-2k(w(x-1)/(2t))}\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &= -\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{2x+a}\mathrm{d}x-\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^kk}{t}e^{kw/t}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-kwx/t}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Now let $x=\frac{a}{2}u$ on the first integral and $x=\frac{t}{kw}v$ on the second, to arrive at two classical Mellin transforms
\begin{align*}I'(w)&=-2^{-s}a^{s-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{s-1}}{u+1}\,\mathrm{d}u-\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^kt^{s-1}}{k^{s-1}}w^{-s}e^{kw/t}\int_{0}^{\infty}v^{s-1}e^{-v}\,\mathrm{d}v
\\ &= -2^{-s}a^{s-1}\pi\csc(\pi s)-t^{s-1}\Gamma(s)w^{-s}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\left(-e^{w/t}\right)^k}{k^{s-1}}\\
&=-2^{-s}a^{s-1}\pi\csc(\pi s)-t^{s-1}\Gamma(s)w^{-s}\operatorname{Li}_{s-1}\left(-e^{w/t}\right),
\end{align*}
which follows from, for example, contour integration or the beta function (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634091/generalisation-of-an-already-generalised-integral?noredirect=1)) and the definition of the gamma function respectively. Here, $\operatorname{Li}$ is the polylogarithm function.

Now note that $I(0)=0$ and $I(1)$ recovers your integral of interest, so $I(1)=\int_{0}^{1}I'(w)\,\mathrm{d}w$, meaning

\begin{align*}I(1)&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(-2^{-s}a^{s-1}\pi\csc(\pi s)-t^{s-1}\Gamma(s)w^{-s}\operatorname{Li}_{s-1}\left(-e^{w/t}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}w\\
&=-2^{-s}a^{s-1}\pi\csc(\pi s) -t^{s-1}\Gamma(s)\int_{0}^{1}w^{-s}\operatorname{Li}_{s-1}\left(-e^{w/t}\right)\,\mathrm{d}w.\end{align*} Letting $w=vt$, we have the final expression,

$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty}\!\!\!x^{s-1}\!\!\left(\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{x-1}{2t}\right)}{2(x-1)}-\frac{1}{2x+a}\right)\!\mathrm{d}x=-2^{-s}a^{s-1}\pi\csc(\pi s) -\Gamma(s)\!\int_{0}^{1/t}\!\!\!\! v^{-s}\operatorname{Li}_{s-1}\left(-e^{v}\right)\,\mathrm{d}v}$$

**Remark:** A remark of perhaps physical relevance is that this integral can also be given in terms of the [complete Fermi-Dirac integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_integral), with $F_{s-2}(v)=-\operatorname{Li}_{s-1}\left(-e^v\right)$, meaning $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1/2}\left(\frac{\tanh\left(\frac{x-1}{2t}\right)}{2(x-1)}-\frac{1}{2x}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\int_{0}^{1/t}v^{-3/2}F_{-1/2}(v)\,\mathrm{d}v.$$

Comment: this was answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4795704/87355